# How to capture all frequencies while recording on smartphones using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, audio, recording

I have been struggling with recording audio data in Javascript.

On the desktop, AudioContext works flawlessly and captures all the frequencies from 20-20K Hz at its unchangeable sampling rate of 44100 Hz.

However, when recording on a smartphone (chrome on Android), even thought the audioContext sets its sample-rate at 48000 Hz (unchangable again!) it captures frequencies upto 6000 Hz only. When I plot its spectrogram on Audacity, it is empty over 6K Hz.

I searched for the solution on internet a lot but seems like no has faced it! 
It's freaking me out. How can javascript sets the sample rate at 48K but captures frequencies till 6k Hz??

Would be really grateful to you guys if you can help me out and point me in the right direction.

following is a similar code taken from https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio/

```
<script>
  var handleSuccess = function(stream) {
    var context = new AudioContext();
    var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var processor = context.createScriptProcessor(1024, 1, 1);

    source.connect(processor);
    processor.connect(context.destination);

    processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
      // Do something with the data, i.e Convert this to WAV
      console.log(e.inputBuffer);
    };
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
      .then(handleSuccess);
</script>
```

I cannot paste my original code since it's for a client.

I have nowhere compressed the code. I generate a wav file from the audio samples on the backend and plot its spectrogram on Audacity.

Comment: I think it's better to post come source code....I think the problem is that you're analyze a compressed recordered file that has frequency cutted from the compression procedure.

Comment: Hi, I have added code and more clarification. please go through it!

Comment: I once had a laptop with a high-order low-pass filter in front of the [ADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) (presumably an [RLC filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#Low-pass_filter), although it might've been a [DSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor)) that produced behavior similar to what you've described. Bottom line is, if you're getting 48000 samples per second, the machine is sampling at 48KHz! But, you can test if this is a hardware issue by checking the spectrum of a recording made with the stock recorder app.

Comment: Yes. as I mentioned in my problem. AudioContext shows that the sample rate is 48K but frequencies above 7K Hz are missing when I plot a spectrogram in Audacity or any other software. Please go through the problem for better clarity.

Comment: @sourabhgupta I'm suggesting that there is no practical way to fix your problem. The higher frequencies are almost certainly being removed by the hardware, not the software. There is no combination of settings or function calls you could make to access or recover this information; as far as the machine is concerned, it never existed.